# Accessing web service with curl, in a /bin/sh script, causes "HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: shell, rest, curl, jersey

If I run the following command, everything works great:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} \
http://www.example.com/mywebservice/generic.example.com \
--header "Content-type: application/json" --request PUT \
--data '{"hostname":"generic.example.com", "project":"none", "usage":"generic", "environment":"production"}'
```

When I put this command into a variable in a /bin/sh script, and execute it, I get "HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type" showing up in the server logs:

```
#!/bin/sh

read -d '' CMD << EOF
curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://www.example.com/mywebservice/generic.example.com \
--header "Content-type: application/json" --request PUT \
--data '{"hostname":"generic.example.com", "project":"none", "usage":"generic", "environment":"production"}'
EOF
`$CMD`
```

I verified the command by printing it out and it looks example like the manual one I run:

```
#!/bin/sh

read -d '' CMD << EOF
curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://www.example.com/mywebservice/generic.example.com \
--header "Content-type: application/json" --request PUT \
--data '{"hostname":"generic.example.com", "project":"none", "usage":"generic", "environment":"production"}'
EOF
echo $CMD
```

Output:

> curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} http://www.example.com/mywebservice/generic.example.com --header "Content-type: application/json" --request PUT --data '{"hostname":"generic.example.com", "project":"none", "usage":"generic", "environment":"production"}'

Comment: What do the headers look like (add the `-i` flag; or `-v` for more verbosity) when the request is sent? Is it still the same?

Comment: @peeskillet -v was definitely informative.  Right off the bat, it showed " Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" so the command wasn't even seeing the --header argument properly.  I think this is an issue with putting commands in a command line.  I'll probably just run it without a variable.

Comment: I ran into the same issue, were you able to figure it out @wsaxton?

Comment: I decided not to put it into a variable and just ran the command directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it worked this way:

```
#!/bin/sh

read -d '' CMD << EOF
`/usr/bin/curl -s http://localhost:8080/someurl \
    --header "Content-type: application/json"`
EOF

echo $CMD
```

What if evaluate it inside of EOF?